# How to add class to form-group div of ActiveField in YII2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have some code below:

```
<?=
  $form->field($model, 'phone_no')->textInput(
    [
      'placeholder' =>
      '(Conditionally validated based on checkbox above, groovy!)'
    ]
  )
?>
```

Which results in HTML:

```
<div class="form-group field-contactform-phone_no">
  <label class="control-label">Phone No
  <input type="text" aria-describedby="hint-contactform-phone_no" placeholder="(Conditionally validated based on checkbox above, groovy!)" name="ContactForm[phone_no]" id="contactform-phone_no" class=""></label>
  <small class="error-box"></small>
  <p class="help-text" id="hint-contactform-phone_no"></p>
</div>
```

My Question is:

How can I add a class 'invisible' to the outer div (containing class=form-group currently)?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 31):

You can do it like this for single field:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone_no', ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group invisible'])
    ->textInput(['placeholder' => '(Conditionally validated based on checkbox above, groovy!)']) ?>
```

Globally (for all fields in form) it's possible like this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldConfig' => ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group invisible']],
]); ?>
```

You can also build `fieldConfig` conditionally:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldConfig' => function ($model, $attribute) {
        if (...) {
            return ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group invisible']],
        }
    },
]); ?>
```

Note that you have to include `form-group` class as well, because it's not merged with your custom one.

**Official docs:**

- [yii\widgets\ActiveField $options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$options-detail)
- [yii\widgets\ActiveForm $fieldConfig](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$fieldConfig-detail)

Comment: Thanks that works pretty good! Now how to make it fadeIn with jQuery (ie remove 'hide' element but make element fadeIn). Will look for it, thanks for the help arogachev

Answer (score 8):

Define the template layout for all the input elements.

```
<?php
                $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                            'id' => 'purchase-sms-temp-form',
                            'layout' => 'horizontal',
                            'fieldConfig' => [
                                'template' => " <div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input\">{label}\n{beginWrapper}\n{input}<div class=\"form-control-focus\"> </div>\n{error}\n</div>{endWrapper}",
                                'horizontalCssClasses' => [
                                    'label' => 'col-md-2 control-label',
                                    'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-4',
                                    'wrapper' => 'col-sm-10',
                                    'error' => 'has-error',
                                    'hint' => 'help-block',
                                ],
                            ],
                ]);
                ?>

                <div class="form-body">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'volume') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'hospital_id') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'created_date') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'complete') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'modified_date') ?>

                </div>
```

For a custom field you can define a class by

```
$form->field($model, 'phone_no', [
          'options' => [
             'class' => 'form-group invisible'
           ])->textInput([
              'placeholder' => '(Conditionally validated based on checkbox above, groovy!)']) ?>
```

Comment: Why define template for just adding class to field container? Second approach is covered in my answer already.

Comment: Missing one closing bracket in custom field, ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group invisible']]